# Linux: How to setup association between gdb and executables?

Tags: linux, debugging, process, gdb, associate

I wish to enable the functionality that when some programs (like my own prog1, prog2,...) when they are brought up by linux as a service daemon, or started within shell, a gdb is automatically started to run these programs.

On windows I can do this with gflags to associated executable files with debuggers. How to do this on linux? I'm running ubuntu 16.04

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider writing a simple wrapper to automatically run gdb after starting a deamon.

Please have a look into `man gdb`.

```
   You can, instead, specify a process ID as a second argument, if you want to debug a running process:

   gdb program 1234

   would attach GDB to process 1234 (unless you also have a file named 1234; GDB does check for a core file first).
```